# Dagger exception when building. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, dagger-2

I need help debugging a dagger exception. 
I tried to build the project and I get this exception 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException
 Here is the code for modules and components.

```
           @Module
         public class AppModule {

            private final StylistaApplication stylistaApplication;


            public AppModule(StylistaApplication stylistaApplication) {
                this.stylistaApplication = stylistaApplication;
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        StylistaApplication provideStylistaApplication() {
            return stylistaApplication;
        }

        @Provides @Singleton
        StylistaRepository provideStylistaRepository(RestDataSource restDataSource){
            return restDataSource;
        }

        @Provides
        Endpoint provideendpoint() {
            return new Endpoint("http://xxxx.com/");
        }

        @Provides @Named("executor_thread")
        Scheduler provideExecutorThread() {
            return Schedulers.newThread();
        }

        @Provides @Named("ui_thread")
        Scheduler provideUiThread() {
            return AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();
        }

    }

    @Module
    public class SignUpModule {
     @Activity
        SignUpUseCase providesignUpUseCase(StylistaRepository stylistaRepository, @Named("executor_Thread")Scheduler executorThread,@Named("ui_thread")Scheduler uiThread){
            return new SignUpUseCase(stylistaRepository,executorThread,uiThread);

        }
}

@Module
public class ActivityModule {
    private final Context mContext;

    public ActivityModule(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Provides
    @Activity
    Context provideActivityContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}

@Singleton @Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    StylistaApplication application();

    @Singleton
    StylistaRepository stylistaRepository();

    Endpoint restEndpoint();

    @Named("executor_thread")
    Scheduler executorThread();

    @Named("ui_thread")
    Scheduler uiThread();



}

@Activity @Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class ,modules = {SignUpModule.class,SignUpModule.class})
public interface SignUpComponent {


    SignUpUseCase signUpUseCase();


}
```

EDIT: Here is the stacktrace for the error:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:157)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:139)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraphValidator$Validation.validateComponentScope(BindingGraphValidator.java:821)
        at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraphValidator$Validation.validateSubgraph(BindingGraphValidator.java:165)
        at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraphValidator.validate(BindingGraphValidator.java:1146)
        at dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessingStep.process(ComponentProcessingStep.java:138)
        at dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessingStep.process(ComponentProcessingStep.java:46)
        at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:318)
        at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:171)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
        ... 86 more
```

Comment: @DavidRawson I have added the stacktrace for the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting scope annotations inside the methods of the component interface is wrong:

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    StylistaApplication application();

    //@Singleton <-- No!!! Don't do this !!!
    StylistaRepository stylistaRepository();

    Endpoint restEndpoint();

    @Named("executor_thread")
    Scheduler executorThread();

    @Named("ui_thread")
    Scheduler uiThread();
}
```

The `@Singleton` annotation before the interface declaration and within the @Provides methods in the modules is enough for Dagger 2 to ensure that the dependencies that are published by the component have the correct scope.

P.S. I think you may be using a different version of Dagger from me (I'm using 2.8) because when I try to put scope annotations inside the components I get this error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.AssertionError: 
ProvisionBinding{
    contributionType=UNIQUE,
    bindingElement=Optional.of(executorService()),
    contributingModule=Optional.absent(),
    key=java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService,
    explicitDependencies=[],
    nullableType=Optional.absent(),
    wrappedMapKey=Optional.absent(),
    bindingKind=COMPONENT_PROVISION,
    membersInjectionRequest=Optional.absent(),
    unresolved=Optional.absent(),
    scope=Optional.of(@com.example.PerApp)
}
```

Comment: When I remove the annotation I get this error. Error:(21, 24) error: com.style.stylista.stylista.rest.RestDataSource cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or from an Provides-annotated method.
com.style.stylista.stylista.app.dependency_injection.Modules.AppModule.provideStylistaRepository(com.style.stylista.stylista.rest.RestDataSource restDataSource)
[parameter: com.style.stylista.stylista.rest.RestDataSource restDataSource]. That is why I had put the scope inside the component.

Comment: In that case you need to write a provider for the RestDataSource. You can include the code in your question

Comment: That solved the problem. It builds successfully now. Thank you.

Comment: @sector11 glad it helped you!